# Is there a way to "document all" equations in AnyLogic System Dynamics model?

Tags: anylogic

There is a convenient *"Document All"* feature in **Vensim** analysis toolbox that allows to print all equations from an active system dynamic model into a text file. An example of some output is as follows:

[image]

Is there similar built-in functionality in **AnyLogic** (PLE version), and if not, is there any workaround?

(I tried the "Documenting a Model" tool but it seems to do different, though useful, things. At least, it prints stuff from "Description" field).

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing beyond the "document a model" capability, no.

Comment: well, the philosophy behind it is likely that "the model is the documentation". Also, AnyLogic is so flexible and generic that there could be 1 million other things that users might want to pull out. But you can always build a way to store anything from your model into a text file, including those equations.